# Shadowbox HTML content size

Tags: shadowbox

Im using Shadowbox (http://www.shadowbox-js.com) to do a modal popup with an external page inside, but i cant get the popup to match the size of the content, it just seems to fill out the screen (with some margin around)

here's my code:

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<!-- jQuery Latest from Google -->
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- MM CSS file -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css" />
<title>Title</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/shadowbox.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/shadowbox.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
Shadowbox.init();
</script>
</head>
```

&

```
<a href="test.html" rel="shadowbox;width:985;height:460">more...</a>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You need to change your code just a little bit. From this:

```
<a href="test.html" rel="shadowbox;width:985;height:460">more...</a>
```

To this (include the equal-sign after width and height, instead of a colon)

```
<a href="test.html" rel="shadowbox;width=985;height=460">more...</a>
```

You can see an example here on the [documentation](http://www.shadowbox-js.com/usage.html) Just search the page for "myswf.swf"

Answer (score 0):

in the line 204, (with netbeans or whatever, right click format)

```
oversized: false
```

That will help you.

On line 1671

```
K.height = S.height; 
K.width = S.width;
```

Thats all